# Calculating weighted sum and sum of columns for report query SQL

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I have a excel sheet in which there is a sample data that I need to show on report.

[image: Excel Sample Data]

As it can be seen that the highlighted 10% is calculating using the formula C11/C21. For the first record C11 = 3900 and C21 = 37250 (Sum of all PO Amount column). So (3900/37250) * 100 = 0.104697 * 100 = 10.4697 or 10%

Similarly Total Weighted is the sum of all Weighted Value column Values.

Now I made the sample data first.

```
CREATE TABLE sample_po_data ("PO_NUMBER", "PO_AMOUNT", "TASK_NAME") AS
  SELECT 4567, 3900, 'Plumbing Rough' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5678, 8000, 'Pour Floor' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 6789, 15000, 'Framing' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 8945, 2500, 'Windows' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5432, 3500, 'Electric' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4321, 450, 'LowVolt' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1234, 3900, 'HVAC Rough' FROM DUAL;
```

Then I used the following query

```
select 
    PO_NUMBER AS "PO #",
    Round((PO_AMOUNT / SUM(PO_AMOUNT) OVER ())*100) || '%' as "Weighted Value",
    PO_AMOUNT AS "PO Amount", 
    Round((PO_AMOUNT / SUM(PO_AMOUNT) OVER ())*100) || '%' as "Total Percent Complete",
    SUM(PO_AMOUNT) OVER () AS "Total Committed And Budgeted"
    -- SUM(Round((PO_AMOUNT / SUM(PO_AMOUNT) OVER ())*100)) OVER () || '%' as "Total Weighted"  -- Total weighted   (Sum of all Weighted Value Column)
    -- % Completed      (Sum of all Total Percent Complete Column)
from sample_po_data;
```

The above query gives the following result

[image: Query Result]

Now how can I sum the `Weighted Value` and `Total Percent Complete` columns ? Both are same.

Also I want to ask the above query is right or there is any better way to write the above query. Actually I am using `SUM(PO_AMOUNT)` in the select three times. Also my two columns are just same.

`Total Committed And Budgeted column` is appearing with all the records. Although I need it just once. Same is true for `Total weighted  column` and `% Completed column`.

How can I make this query better ?

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including: the `CREATE TABLE` statement(s) for a **MINIMAL** example of your data; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data that is representative of the problem; and the expected output for that sample data (all as **TEXT** we can copy/paste, not images). If you can reduce the problem to a an example using only two or three columns and a single table then you should; we do not need to know about the joins between 5 tables having 20 columns (you can make it more complicated later but make it simple for us so we only have to solve one problem).

Comment: @MTO I have added the minimal reproducible example. can you look at it now please ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SUM` as an analytic function and conditional aggregation:

```sql
select 
    PO_NUMBER AS "PO #",
    Round(PO_AMOUNT / SUM(PO_AMOUNT) OVER () * 100) AS "Weighted Value",
    PO_AMOUNT AS "PO Amount",
    Completion_Date,
    Round(
      CASE WHEN completion_date IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE PO_AMOUNT END
      / SUM(PO_AMOUNT) OVER () * 100
    ) AS "Percent Complete",
    SUM(PO_AMOUNT) OVER () AS "Total Committed And Budgeted",
    -- This will always add up to 100%; you do not need to calculate it.
    100 as "Total Weighted",
    Round(
      SUM(CASE WHEN completion_date IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE PO_AMOUNT END) OVER ()
      / SUM(PO_AMOUNT) OVER () * 100
    ) AS "Total Percent Complete"
from sample_po_data;
```

Which, for the sample data (with a `COMPLETION_DATE` column added):

```sql
CREATE TABLE sample_po_data (PO_NUMBER, PO_AMOUNT, COMPLETION_DATE, TASK_NAME) AS
          SELECT 4567,  3900, DATE '2021-01-01', 'Plumbing Rough' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5678,  8000, DATE '2021-02-01', 'Pour Floor' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 6789, 15000, DATE '2021-03-01', 'Framing' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 8945,  2500, NULL,              'Windows' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 5432,  3500, NULL,              'Electric' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 4321,   450, NULL,              'LowVolt' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1234,  3900, NULL,              'HVAC Rough' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | PO # | Weighted Value | PO Amount | COMPLETION_DATE | Percent Complete | Total Committed And Budgeted | Total Weighted | Total Percent Complete |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 4567 | 10 | 3900 | 01-JAN-21 | 10 | 37250 | 100 | 72 |
> | 5678 | 21 | 8000 | 01-FEB-21 | 21 | 37250 | 100 | 72 |
> | 6789 | 40 | 15000 | 01-MAR-21 | 40 | 37250 | 100 | 72 |
> | 8945 | 7 | 2500 |  | 0 | 37250 | 100 | 72 |
> | 5432 | 9 | 3500 |  | 0 | 37250 | 100 | 72 |
> | 4321 | 1 | 450 |  | 0 | 37250 | 100 | 72 |
> | 1234 | 10 | 3900 |  | 0 | 37250 | 100 | 72 |

---

For your full query:

```sql
SELECT poh.po_full_number AS "PO #", 
       100 * poh.po_total_amount / SUM(poh.po_total_amount) OVER ()
         AS "Weighted Value",
       poh.po_total_amount AS "PO Amount", 
       poh.approve_date AS "PO Approved Date", 
       st.task_name AS "Task Name", 
       st.start_date AS "Task Projected Start Date",
       st.original_finish_date AS "Actual End Date",
       SUM(poh.po_total_amount) OVER () AS "Total Committed And Budgeted",
       100 AS "Total weighted"
       SUM(
         CASE WHEN st.end_date IS NOT NULL THEN poh.total_amount ELSE 0 END
       ) OVER () / SUM(poh.po_total_amount) OVER () * 100
         AS "% Completed"
FROM   po_header poh
       inner join unit u on poh.unit_id = u.unit_id 
       inner join company_project cp on poh.project_id = cp.project_id 
       inner join company_project_setting cps on cp.project_id = cps.project_id
       inner join po_header_status_lk pohslk on poh.po_status = pohslk.code 
       LEFT JOIN schedule_task st on poh.schedule_task_id = st.schedule_task_id 
WHERE  poh.project_id = 511                           
AND    poh.po_type = 100 
AND    poh.po_status = 101                                                 
AND    u.status_id in (102, 103)                                       
AND    (  (cps.construction_type = 1 AND st.is_finished = 1)
       OR (cps.construction_type in (0, 2) AND st.is_finished != 1))            
order by
       poh.po_header_id desc;
```